# Append the DataFrame and add the conditions in the for loop

Tags: python

I am trying to return the data frame by using the conditions. How to handle the condition when there are two features like height and weight in the below example as my code right now takes only the second condition by replacing the previous one.
df['conditions'] values are as follows: height <= 9.10 & weight <= 89

Right now it only does the following while returning :

df_store_cond1 = df_store.loc[(df_store[weight] <= float(89))]

However what I would want to do something like below before returning the dataframe so it checks both the conditions:

df_store_cond1 = df_store.loc[(df_store[weight] <= float(89)) & (df_store[height] <= float(9.10))]

```
def func(sno): 
    df_store = X_train.copy()  #copying the dataframe to another df
    features = features_list = df['conditions'].tolist()[int(sno)]
    if '&' in features:
        if '&' and '<=' in features:
            for k in features.split('&'):
                print(features)
                j = k.replace(' ','')
                if '<=' in j:
                    operator1 = j.split('<=')
                df_store_cond1 = df_store.loc[(df_store[str(operator1[0])] <= float(operator1[1]))]
            return df_store_cond1
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code create new `df_store_cond1` every for loop.
Try to update your code like this:

```
def func(sno): 
    df_store = X_train.copy()  #copying the dataframe to another df
    features = features_list = df['conditions'].tolist()[int(sno)]
    if '&' in features:
        if '&' and '<=' in features:
            for k in features.split('&'):
                print(features)
                j = k.replace(' ','')
                if '<=' in j:
                    operator1 = j.split('<=')
                df_store = df_store.loc[(df_store[str(operator1[0])] <= float(operator1[1]))]
            return df_store
```

Comment: Thanks much for pointing out. It was a silly mistake:).